# How can I configure default database in a connection string?

Tags: sql, ssms, connection-string, alteryx

I am seeking to write a batch macro in alteryx that will allow us to more effectively log our sandbox write history and enable our team members to utilize the sandbox in an easier fashion..

However, when we write out to the database, the macro returns a permission denied in the database - It references the default database but it is not mentioned or used in the macro at all.

I was wondering if it is possible to declare the default database in the connection string?

Comment: Can you add `Initial Catalog=DatabaseName` to whatever connection string you have?

Comment: This worked! thank you

Comment: Cool - I'll add it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Initial Catalog=DatabaseName` in your connection string.